# CREATE USER produces 'NOTICE: empty string is not valid...'

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm following the PostgreSQL docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createuser.html to create a user.  psql hates me.

```
# CREATE USER blah WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md56f1ed002ab5595859014ebf0951522d9';
NOTICE:  empty string is not a valid password, clearing password
CREATE ROLE
```

I generated the MD5 like...

```
$ md5 -s 'blah'
MD5 ("blah") = 6f1ed002ab5595859014ebf0951522d9
```

How do I get the `NOTICE:  empty string is not a valid password, clearing password` to go away and have postgres respect my desire to present it with an encrypted password?

Comment: If you are sure that is your password, you must have some extension or modification in your PostgreSQL that replaces it with an empty string.

Comment: `CREATE USER blah PASSWORD 'md56f1ed002ab5595859014ebf0951522d9'`

Comment: @Ancoron.  No joy with the `CREATE USER blah PASSWORD 'md56f1ed002ab5595859014ebf0951522d9'` variant.  exact same error.  THis is a stock brew installed postgres.  psql says `psql (11.2)`

Comment: Wow.  It might be objecting to my user name and password being the same?!?!  `CREATE USER blah PASSWORD 'md54adde5216371c71cc717e56c347e130d';` succeeds.

Comment: Ah yes, they did that for MD5 because otherwise it would be way too easy to break in...

Comment: Just found how to do the MD5 hashing properly (which then also works): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-authid.html So that's the actual reason the simple MD5 hash of the clear text username value will never work (and why it correctly states that the password is "empty").

Comment: @Ancoron I had completely forgotten about the "combine the password and role name into a single string" part.  That is probably what was killing me all along.  My MD5 was on just the password, it needs to also include the rolename.  The postgres "optimization" that CREATE USER is actually CREATE ROLE further clouded the issue.

Comment: @BobKuhar Yes, that fooled me as well. :-)